# Why use a particular regularization for $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,e^{i p x}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, regularization, wick-rotation

There are many badly defined integrals in physics.
I want to discuss one of them which I see very often. 
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,e^{i p x}$$
I have seen this integral in many physical problems. Many people seem to think it is a well defined integral, and is calculated as follows:

We will use regularization (we introduce a small real parameter $\varepsilon$ and after calculation set $\varepsilon = 0$.

$$I_0=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,e^{i p x}e^{ -\varepsilon x}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon-i p}=\frac{i}{p}$$

But I can obtain an arbitrary value for this integral!
I will use regularization too, but I will use another parametrization:

$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,e^{i p x}=\int_0^\infty dx \left(1+\alpha\frac{\varepsilon \sin px}{p}\right)e^{i p x}e^{ -\varepsilon x}$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a regularization parameter and $\alpha$ is an arbitrary value
using $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,\sin{(\alpha x)} e^{ -\beta x}=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$

After a not-so-difficult calculation I obtain that
$I(\alpha)=\frac{i}{p}\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$.

This integral I have often seen in intermediate calculation. But usually people do not take into account of this problem, and just use $I_0$. I don't understand why?

I know only one example when I can explain why we should use $I_0$. In field theory when we calculate $U(-\infty,0)$, where $U$ is an evolution operator, It is proportional to $\int^0_{-\infty} \mathrm{d}t\,e^{ -iE t}$. It is necessary for the Weizsaecker-Williams approximation in QED, or the DGLAP equation in QCD, because in axiomatic QFT we set $T\to \infty(1-i\varepsilon)$.

My question is: Why, in calculation of the integral $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,e^{i p x}$, do people use $I_0$? Why people use $e^{ -\varepsilon x}$ regularization function? In my point of view this regularization no better and no worse than another.

Comment: You have discovered the difference between physics and mathematics. $I_0$ just works better.

Comment: Many smart people have worked on trying to formalise the regularisation technique self consistently. Eventually though, to make sense of anything in physics you have to compare with experiment. Calculation of the Casimir force by using Zeta functions is the famous example here. One must then choose a specific parameterisation to obtain an answer that agrees. As for your $I_{0}$ specifically, I could not say. I have never been really satisfied with the 'divergence removing' techniques much either.

Comment: Amazingly, it doesn't matter how you regularize, as long as you do so consistently. The finite part of the regularisation of the divergent series/integral will always agree, see [this post from Terry Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/).

Comment: I hope this adds another little clarification. Step function: $\mathbb{1}_{[0,+\infty)}(x)\in \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, that gives $1$ if $x\in[0,+\infty)$, $0$ otherwise. Fourier transform maps $\mathscr{S}'$ into itself. The Fourier transform of the step function above ***uniquely*** defines your integral, as a distribution on $\mathscr{S'}$; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Fourier_transform) for an explicit form. The ambiguities mathematically rise from the fact that "exchanging the limit with the integral" is not permitted in this case.

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1507474/11127

Answer (score 4):

When you introduce an auxiliary variable, such as a regularization parameter, at the end of the calculation you have to take the limit that sets the expression back to the original one. If you introduce multiple auxiliary variables, you have to do this for *all* of them. Otherwise you're just doing a different integral. In this case specifically,

$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)
&=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,e^{i p x} \\
&=\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_0^\infty dx \left(1+\alpha\frac{\varepsilon \sin px}{p}\right)e^{i p x}e^{ -\varepsilon x} \\
&= \lim_{\alpha\to 0} I(\alpha) \\
&= I(0) = I_0
\end{align}$$

Without the $\lim_{\alpha\to 0}$, you're not calculating $\int e^{ipx}$, you're calculating something else.

Sure, if you put the $\varepsilon$ limit inside the integral then it *looks* like the value of $\alpha$ doesn't matter, but you can't actually make that conclusion, because limits don't commute with integrals in general. And clearly, in this case, the value of $\alpha$ *does* matter.

Comment: $\alpha$ is not a regularization parameter. It is arbitrary number.I mean that $\left(1+\alpha\frac{\varepsilon \sin px}{p}\right)e^{ -\varepsilon x}$ is a regularization function for arbitrary $\alpha$

Comment: Yes, but the point of my answer is that $\bigl(1 + \alpha\frac{\varepsilon\sin px}{p}\bigr)e^{ipx}e^{-\epsilon x}$ is not the same as $e^{ipx}e^{-\epsilon x}$. It's a different integrand and integrating it will give you a different result. This is true whether you call $\alpha$ a regularization parameter or not.

Comment: But it is not answer on my question. I don't understand why people use such regularization $e^{-\varepsilon x}$. In my point of view this regularization  no better and no worse in mathematical point of view.

Comment: Ah, it seemed like you were asking why people use $I_0$ instead of using $I(\alpha)$ for some arbitrary $\alpha$. If you're asking why people use the regularization $e^{-\varepsilon x}$ at all, that's a little different. (And in that case, I don't see what $I(\alpha)$ has to do with the question) Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify?

Comment: @DavidZ I think Peter's point is that both integrands are equal to $e^{ipx}$ when you let $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Ahsan yes, that's how I understood it. My point in the answer was that, simply because both integrands are equal in this limit, it does not mean that both integrals are equal when you take the limit after integrating. I'm not quite sure how best to say so, though.

Comment: Alright, so limits and integrals don't commute in general. But then I guess the OP's asking how does one decide what value to assign to the integral above, since there are many different non-equivalent choices, as he has demonstrated.

Comment: @Ahsan but my point is precisely that the OP has _not_ demonstrated that there are many different non-equivalent choices. Only the choice where $\alpha=0$ corresponds to the original integral.

Comment: No.  In mathematical point of view both regularization function are normal. This integral is bad define, because the answer dependence on regularization function

Comment: @DavidZ I added an answer based on my interpretation of the point you were making. Did I interpret it correctly?

Comment: @user76284 I think your answer might be a little different (but definitely related and definitely a good point to make) . I'm not sure at the moment, though.

Answer (score 2):

Something that fixes $\frac{i}{p}$ uniquely is that, independently of regulator, it is the constant term of the asymptotic expansion of
$$\int_0^b \mathrm{e}^{ipx} \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{i - \mathrm{e}^{ipb}}{p}$$

Moreover, consider applying your regulator with $\alpha \neq 0$ to a case where the integral *does* converge, such as $p=i$. Does it still yield the correct answer? Naively, one might think the second term in the integrand doesn't matter because $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ so $\frac{\varepsilon \sin p x}{p} \rightarrow 0$. The same would be true in this convergent scenario. But it clearly *does* matter because $\alpha \neq 0$ yields the wrong answer. Thus you *must* let $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ at the end, or your method will be inconsistent with convergent integrals.